# Compiler error only in Android Studio but not in Gradle build: abstract base class member getLifecycle() not implemented

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-lifecycle

In my Android project in AndroidStudio a class (named MyService below), which extends LifecycleService, is marked with the following error message:

*Class 'MyService' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member **public abstract fun** getLifecycle(): Lifecycle defined in androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleService*

But the build with Gradle is fine, and when I navigate to the class LifecycleService, it is neither abstract nor is the getLifecycle method missing, due to the following definition:

```
override val lifecycle: Lifecycle
    get() = dispatcher.lifecycle
```

which should fulfill the interface method getLifecycle of LifeCycleOwner.

So it seems, that AndroidStudio is using other libraries than Gradle. But when I navigate in AndroidStudio it seems, that the gradle libraries are used.
Any explanation, what is going on here, and how I can fix it?

Comment: I am experiencing this as well. I think it might actually be more along the lines of a dependency clash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem in transitive library dependencies

**Explanation**

`AppCompat`, `Activity`, `Fragment` and other `AndroidX` libraries have outdated versions of `lifecycle-common` library in their dependencies. Apparently you are using a new version of the lifecycle dependency in one of the modules, but in other modules you are not using it at all and the older version is automatically selected.
The new version of lifecycle has changed the description of the `androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner` interface and therefore Android Studio considers them different

**Lifecycle version 2.6.1**

```kotlin
public interface LifecycleOwner {

    public val lifecycle: Lifecycle
}
```

**Lifecycle version 2.5.1**

```java
public interface LifecycleOwner {

    @NonNull
    Lifecycle getLifecycle();
}
```

**Solution 1:**

You need to explicitly specify the new version of the `lifecycle-common` dependency in the other modules (not necessarily in all, but only in those where `lifecycle` is used transitively)

```kotlin
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1'
```

**Solution 2:**

You can roll back versions of lifecycle libraries to 2.5.1, which is used in the latest version of the library currently "`androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1`

```kotlin
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.5.1'
```

Comment: Great. I searched for all dependencies to androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1 in my modules and added a dependency to androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1. (Solution 1). After that the error message was gone. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks that gave me the hint to troubleshoot. I tried adding the lifecycle-common dependency to some of the modules that were using appcompat and fragment, but didn't work... we have over 50 modules... looks like the issue was only in 1 module that had the `androidx.work:work-runtime`. I ended up adding the `resolutionStrategy.force('androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1')` in the build.gradle (project)